# WMI query escape single quote

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

```
string dirName = @"D:\Test't";
string qry = "associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='" + dirName + "'} where assocclass = Win32_SubDirectory ResultRole = PartComponent";
```

While executing the above WMI query, I am getting **Invalid object path** exception. How to escape single quote in WMI query?

Comment: If it is a folder created by you, remove single quote by renaming it.

Comment: TRY THIS:  string dirName = "D:\\Test\'t";

Comment: @GaurangDave NOT working.

Comment: If @, or using backslashes is not working, you have another issue.  Inspect the "qry" string, and try to run it manually outside of your app

Comment: What do you need? I mean what is the purpose of doing this? By pasting two lines here, it is difficult to find out what you want. Please edit  your question and put more details

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I was using VBScript, the query I was using looked like this:

```
qry = "Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='" & dirName & "'} Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent"
```

I change it to the following and the issue was fixed, I simply change the single quote to a double quote but I had to double the double quotes because that is how a double quote is escaped in VBScript.

```
qry = "Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name=""" & dirName & """} Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent"
```